I am encountering a server error when building a server to perform tesseract OCR analysis of image uploaded
I am building an Express.js server that uses Multer for file uploads and Tesseract.js for Optical Character Recognition (OCR). However, I am encountering a couple of issues:
404 Error: When sending a POST request to the /ocr endpoint, I am receiving a 404 Not Found error
I used Postman to send a POST request to http://localhost:3000/ocr and received 500 error code stating "error": "OCR processing failed"
This is my code, can anyone advise on where I am going wrong here:
const express = require("express");
const multer = require("multer");
const Tesseract = require("tesseract.js");
const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs");

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

// Set up Multer for file uploads
const upload = multer({ dest: "uploads/" });

// Define the /ocr route
app.post("/ocr", upload.single("image"), async (req, res) => {
  try {
    if (!req.file) {
      return res.status(400).json({ error: "No file uploaded" });
    }

    const imagePath = path.join(__dirname, req.file.path);
    console.log('Image Path:', imagePath);

    const {
      data: { text },
    } = await Tesseract.recognize(imagePath, "eng");

    console.log(`${req.method} request to ${req.url}`);

    fs.unlinkSync(imagePath);

    res.json({ text });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error details:', error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: "OCR processing failed" });
  }
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on http://localhost:${port}`);
});


Be sure to include all error logs, not just what you are sending in try/catch. A 404 cannot become a 500 on the same route
